# Identify this game: breaking into a museum to restore exhibits, ran on a Mac

Tags: macos, game-identification, msdos

So, I'm looking for a game that involves breaking into a museum, it is a point-and-click adventure.

I remember playing it on the old Macs, the ones that had different color cases and a really old OS.

The premise was you had to break into the Museum for something, but you had to cross through a labryinth, and you had to find keycards to get you into the museum. Like below (old image):

[image]

But after you got into the museum, you had to restore the exhibits one by one, and different parts of different exhibits could be found in other exhibits.  And you could interact with the exhibits, there was one in like a fair, there was one where you could explore a nuclear reactor, and Louis and Clark exhibits.

Comment: Oh god I remember playing this in 3rd grade with my friends

Comment: @slow_excellence same, played in way back in elementary school, too bad I graduated before I could ever finish it.

Comment: I feel like it's one of those games that nobody has completed because they had limited time to play at school and wound up moving on to the next grade before they could beat it lol

Comment: @slow_excellence Yeah yeah, exactly.  It was I think 30 min of gameplay each week, so you really didnt have much time to play it all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The game is called Museum Madness. [From Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Museum_Madness_(video_game)):

> The game starts in the bedroom of an American high school teenage boy
>   who is seated at his computer, attempting to access the National
>   Museum Interactive Service System, only to see that it is offline for
>   repair. An interactive robot from the museum named MICK (Museum
>   Interactive Computer Kiosk) appears onscreen and talks to the boy,
>   explaining that the museum is in danger of losing its secrets forever.
>   The boy appears to have an extraordinary relationship with MICK as he
>   alone understands that MICK can talk back to him, which he uses to
>   learn more about the contents of the museum. MICK recognizes this
>   understanding and thus asks the boy for help to save the museum. MICK
>   explains that the exhibits have come to life and are acting very
>   strangely. He announces his suspicion that a virus has infected the
>   system while the museum was being converted to complete autonomous
>   computer control.

Older images I found that I recognize:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This game is [Mystery at the Museums](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mystery_at_the_Museums).

***Short Synopsis: (copied n pasted from wiki)***

The objective of Mystery at the Museums is to find all of the artifacts that have gone missing from the Smithsonian Museum before an inspector comes to visit at 10:00am the next morning. The artifacts have been scattered throughout the different Smithsonian museums, and the player must visit each of these museums and solve puzzles in order to get the artifacts back. The puzzles are all derived from popular existing puzzles, like cube folding puzzles, sliding puzzles, or Tetris puzzles, but have a museum theme and give the information about various museum as the puzzles are solved. When the player correctly solves the puzzle, if there was an artifact there, the game will cut back to the curator's office and Edison will inform the curator that he has found an artifact. If there was no artifact to be found, the player will be taken back to the map screen and will have to choose another area to search. When the player has found all of the artifacts, he must then complete a maze in order to find out why all of the artifacts went missing in the first place.